# using tkinter to call computer camera and gets an error:invalid command name ".!toplevel.!canvas"

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to use tkinter to call the computer camera and save the picture for further process. The capture works fine and I can successfully call the camera and see myself, but every time I click the 'save_pic' button, nothing happens, and then I close the window and this error came up. I've been trying to search the similar questions but still get no satisfactory answer for my procedure.  This is driving me crazy. Please help me with with this. Thank you very much in advance!

```
def shot_pic():
    global flag#use flag to save the picture
    global filename
    flag = 0
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640) #set the size of bg
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480) 

    top = Toplevel()#use toplevel to generate the window because I have a mainnwindow in the main function
    top.title('camera shot')
    frm_top = Frame(top)
    Button(top, height=2, width=8, text='save picture',command=save_pic).pack(side=TOP)
    canvas = Canvas(top, bg='black', height=480, width=640)
    canvas.pack()

    #capture video
    while (capture.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = capture.read() #ret shows that whether I get the video frame
        if ret:
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            image_file = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=image_file)#draw the picture on the bg
            canvas.image_file = image_file
            frm_top.update_idletasks()
            frm_top.update()

        if flag==1:#save picture
            cv2.imwrite("cut_img.jpg", frame)  
            img = cv2.imread('cut_img.jpg')
            img = img[110:420,180:490]  #set size of pic
            img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
            cv2.imwrite("cut_img.jpg", img)  
            filename = "cut_img.jpg"
            break

    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    top.destroy()
    pic_name = "cut_img.jpg"
    img1 = Image.open(pic_name)  #return the picture to the mainwindow
    photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
    img_label1.config(imag=photo1)
    mainloop()
def save_pic():#the button function of save picture
    flag = 1
    return
```

and the error below:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\miniconda3\envs\gluon\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "GUI.py", line 45, in shot_pic
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=image_file)
  File "E:\miniconda3\envs\gluon\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2489, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "E:\miniconda3\envs\gluon\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!canvas"
```

Comment: I think you need to add `global flag` inside `save_pic()` as well.

Comment: It works! I'm so careless. Thank you  sooooo much!!!! :)